# Loop custom field images

Tags: php, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

So I'm working with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Wordpress 4.1.1 and I created 4 custom fields: "topIMG", "leftIMG", "centerIMG", "rightIMG". I made them images so I can add more images to the post and place them a specific area on my page.

So originally I wanted to display just one image to get it work and this was my code to display one image:

```
<?php
$image = get_field('topimg');
$link = get_field('link', $image['id']);
?>
<div class="images">
<section id="topIMG">
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
</section>
</div>
```

This works and displays the image. Now I tried to create a foreach loop so I can also display the rest of the images too. Here is that code:

```
<?php
    $array = array('topimg', 'leftimg', 'centerimg', 'rightimg');
    $image = get_field($array);
    $link = get_field('link', $image['id']);
    $output = '<div class="images">';

    foreach($image as $image) {
        $output .= '<section id='.$array.'>';
        $output .= '<img src='.$link.'>';
        $output .= '</section>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

When I view this on the site, I get errors and I'm unsure how to correctly display those images. Help is much appreciated.

The errors I'm seeing:

Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php on line 268

Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-includes/meta.php on line 499

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/RyanPortfolio/single.php on line 17

Comment: The first two errors aren't in this part of your code... they seems to be in your `get_field` function, can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over this array to use each of the images:

```
<?php
$array = array('topimg', 'leftimg', 'centerimg', 'rightimg');
$output = '<div class="images">';
foreach($array as $v){
    $image = get_field($v);
    if($v == 'centerimg'){
        $link = $image['value'];
    }else{
        $link = $image['value']['url'];
    }
    $output .= '<section id='.$v.'>';
    $output .= '<img src='.$link.' />';
    $output .= '</section>';
 }
$output .= '</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried this which I really appreciate the help, but now I get these two errors:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/RyanPortfolio/single.php on line 16

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/RyanPortfolio/single.php on line 17

Comment: That means that `$image` is string there and you cannot access ['id']. You need to var_dump this $image after `$image = get_field('topimg');` in your first example - what is that? Not an array? If the first example worked, this one must work too, the $image is obtained in the same way.

Comment: So my code will look like this?

$image = get_field($v);
var_dump $image  

Is that correct?

Comment: yes, and/or `$image = get_field('topimg'); var_dump($image);` from your first example that works.

Comment: Why do it to the first example? I dont want to have to repeat all that code to display those images. 

I did it to the answer you gave me and I still have those errors but the "var_dump" displays the code for that image

Comment: second line of your code that worked has `$image['id']` which indicates that $image is array. Now the new errors say it is a string. So in first round of loop in my answer, `$image = get_field($v);` is the same as `$image = get_field('topimg');` I don't know in which iteration you see that error and what that function `get_field` returns. Maybe try to do it first for `$array=('topimg');` - it should have the same result as your first code. Maybe for one of those remaining values this function returns a string, or empty string if not exists?

Comment: I understand the first version which I displayed first works and also understand that $image=get_field($v) is the same as $image=get_field('topimg'). But I don't understand why I need to do a var_dump when it doesn't display the image but just random code where it gets the image. How is that supposed to help? 

I'm sorry I'm not that advanced at this if you can't tell already. But what I did to get rid of the errors from displaying was do this instead. $image=get_field_object($v); but the images dont display and display the "broken image" link http://dev.ryanlebo.com/projects/urxscape-website/

Comment: No no! I wanted you to do `var_dump` only for a moment, for debugging, for me or you to see what is the structure of $image - is it array, and if it is, what keys it has. While you write code, it is very useful to see what in a given moment is behind the given variable name. Of course you delete it immediately after you check. You can also use gettype($image) to see whether it is a string or array.

Comment: There view it since I'm doing var_dump. I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: I see it, but if it is after get_field, it means that $image is array and has id. It also means the array is iterated OK, but something is wrong with that get_field function. If your first code works OK, this one should too. Try to omit that $link - give the section id = `$v` and src=`$image['url']` - I am changing to it in answer!

Comment: Now I edited - closed img tag - `/>` - maybe that is the reason? If not, echo out what is in `$image['url']`. Now it is exactly as your first code!

Comment: Where do I echo the $image['url']

Comment: just after  $image = get_field($v); - but again, only for a moment, just to make sure it is the url that exists, and not another array or something else

Comment: Ok so I did `echo $image['url']` and nothing happened

Comment: I also just typed `echo $image` and that said ArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: OK, I see that in that $image array there is another array, so change `$image['url']` to `$image['value']['url']`

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! HOLY COW thank you so much!!!! BTW.. even though this works, There is an error displayed at the top of the first image:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in /home1/rlebo59/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/RyanPortfolio/single.php on line 18

Comment: Ok it worked for the "topimg" id but I also have an image already in the wordpress side for the "centerimg" and that doesn't display.. However, if i take out the `['url']` and just have `$image['value']` then the image for "topimg" disappears and "centerimg" displays then??

Comment: yes, you can see it in your var_dump - in case of centerimage it is value. You need to add 'if' condition to take value if its center and value url if it is top

Comment: Ok, so how would I write that?